# How to use Android call WCF ..?

Tags: android, wcf

How to write Android call WCF (It's a “.svc“ web) code?

I tried to read related articles.

Finally with the library (ksoap2), but still can not succeed.

If the WCF (.svc web) contains a function (Adder).
How do I call the function (Adder)?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so much *how can Android call WCF?* rather *how can Android call a SOAP Service?*  Try googling that.  By definition it should not matter *how* the SOAP service is implemented; .NET or not; Java or not.

Same applies if the WCF service is JSON instead of SOAP.